# On Tap Change View Visual Properties From Standard View Method Without Totally Rebuilding It

Tags: swiftui

I have thought of two ways of changing a view property without totally rebuilding it.

If tapped, I want my `Color.red` to have a border, like if it was selected...

I have tried

```swift
 struct SelectableColor: View, CustomizationOption {
    @State var selected: Bool = false
    
    
    var color: Color = Color.red
    
    init(color: Color) {
        self.color = color
        
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        if selected {
            color
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 6, x: 0, y: 3)
                .border((.red))
                .onTapGesture {
                    selected = false
                }
        }else{
            color
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 6, x: 0, y: 3)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selected = true
                }
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

but it rebuilds the entire view... we could also try having a border with zero width and change its width with a state variable... it would work, but now this question will only help just small amount of people in the feature because we have an invisible border, something you can do when you want to do something like resizing or whatever.

In short, I need a way to say, add `.border(.blue)` to a view that does not have it, on the fly, and without rebuilding the entire view.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question?

Comment: Hello, I have added "In short, I need a way to say, add .border(.blue) to a view that does not have it, on the fly, and without rebuilding the entire view" to the question, @NoeOnJupiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following `.border(selected ? .red: .clear)`. `if statement` redraws the `View` because you're creating a new `View` when the state changes, whereas this should only update since it's the same `View`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simplified just like this

```
var body: some View {
    color
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 6, x: 0, y: 3)
        .border(selected ? .blue : .clear)            // << here !!
        .onTapGesture {
            selected.toggle()  // << here !!
        }
}
```